# Finding a comparison series for $\frac{\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}}{\sqrt{k^3+2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've tried a number of other convergence tests to no avail and I have a hunch that either an ordinary/limit comparison test is probably where I need to be looking. I'm not looking for a direct answer here, rather some guidance in how to choose comparison series in situations like this.

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}}{\sqrt{k^3+2}}$$

My initial thought was to look at $$\frac{k^\frac{2}{3}}{k^\frac{3}{2}}$$ as it follows the leading terms of $a_n$ but it doesn't match the conditions for the ordinary comparison test. I'm at a bit of a loss for the process of finding a $b_n$ as we didn't do much of this sort of work in class.

Thanks!

Comment: You were almost there. $$\frac{k^\frac{2}{3}}{k^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{k^{5/6}}$$ is greater than the harmonic series, then it diverges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial thought was correct, but you have to use some elementary asymptotic analysis: as a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, we  have $k^2+1\sim_\infty k^2$, $\:k^3+2\sim_\infty k^3$, so
$$ \sqrt[3]{k^2+1}\sim_\infty k^{\tfrac23},\enspace\sqrt{k^3+2}\sim_\infty k^{\tfrac32}, \quad\text{whence}\quad \frac{\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}}{\sqrt{k^3+2}}\sim_\infty \frac{ k^{\tfrac23}}{k^{\tfrac32}}=\frac 1{k^{\tfrac56}},$$
which is a divergent $p$-series.

Answer (score 1):

For large $k$, $1$ is tiny compared to $k^2$ and $2$ is tiny compared to $k^3$. We can write

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}}{\sqrt{k^3+2}}=k^{-5/6}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac1{k^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{k^3}}}.$$

The factor $k^{-5/6}$ carries the main contribution of the expression, and the ratio tends to $1$.

It is not very hard to find two limits such that

$$a\le\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac1{k^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{k^3}}}\le b$$ as of some $k$. For example, $\dfrac12$ and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know equivalents or are afraid to use them, remember that you can often use rough inequalities instead.

$\sqrt[3]{k^2+1}\ge\sqrt[3]{k^2}=k^{2/3}$

$\sqrt{k^3+2}\le\sqrt{k^3+3k^3}=2k^{3/2}$ since obviously $2<3k^3$ for $k\ge 1$.

You get $a_k\ge \dfrac{k^{2/3}}{2k^{3/2}}\ge \dfrac 1{2k^{5/6}}$ which is a term of a divergent series.